# Efficient polling algorithm to poll a queue count. Poll more often as the number gets closer to the target

Tags: algorithm, queue

I have a loop that polls a queue waiting for the queue to reach a target value. Once the queue reaches that target value then I initiate another action.

At the moment I have just set the polling to 5 seconds but what I would like to do is vary the polling frequency depending on how far away I am from the target. So if my target valus is 10000 messages on the queue and I start polling the queue. The first count is say 5 items. I sleep for 5 seconds then poll again and the number is 20 items etc. What I would like to do is do the first poll which brings back a count of 5 but then sleep longer because I am so far away from the target value. As I get close to my target value I want to poll more often. So as I approach a count of 10000 my delay is perhaps a second in length.

What would be an efficient algorithm for implementing that.

Comment: Interpolate the remaining time from the past pollings (and the values you got) depending on the jitter of your values sleep for e.g. 3/4 of the estimated time from the interpolation.

Comment: Try to go other way around. Every time a message is added to the queue, increment the counter. Once it reaches the target, initiate the action. No need to sleep longer or shorter.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will have to have another look at it